# Do we know a MD5 collision exploiting PHP loose type comparision (0123e2 == 123e02 == 012300)?

Tags: hash, php

Since PHP has loose type comparison, we have:

```
php -r 'var_dump("1234e03"=="1234000");'
bool(true)
```

And since MD5 hashs are often reprensented as hexa string like `713f44b3d2c680df02eb5a0bde86fcd7`

Are there two already known values that make a MD5 collison for PHP loose type comparison like `md5($value1) == md5($value2)` ?

With the snippet
`time crunch 1 6|pv|php -r '$x=fopen("php://stdin","r");while ($l=trim(fgets($x))) {if (is_numeric(md5($l))) { echo "$l\t".md5($l)."\n"; exit; } }'` I found that `ecrbx` yields `0310763137713908293306e502423361` which is a number in scientific notation. So I guess such collisions could be easier to do than plain simple collisions, but I don't know any example.

The same question would apply for other hash functions, like SHA1, SHA256, etc but would probably be harder to answer

Comment: Yes. This is a known issue and have a known solution: use `===` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are often known as "magic hashes", and have been found for lots of different hashing algorithms. You can find a list of them [here](https://github.com/spaze/hashes).

The easiest way to find them to to look for a hash output that starts with `0e`, and the rest of the hash is all numbers (because zero times 10 to the power of anything is zero).

For example, for MD5 `240610708` hashes to `0e462097431906509019562988736854` and  and `QLTHNDT` hashes to `0e405967825401955372549139051580`:

```
$ php -r 'var_dump(md5("240610708") == md5("QLTHNDT"));'
bool(true)
```

Comment: Neat, thanks, I didn't know that "magic hashes" name (and didn't think of the `0e` idea :) )